# Knockout/Select2 Dropdownlist contains correct options, but now displays nothing as selected

Tags: knockout.js, jquery-select2

So I have two dropdown lists that I'm using with knockout and select. When the availablePeople list returns all false (doesn't work properly), I am able to select and retain the person I chose. However, when the available people list works properly, I am not able to see the dropdown selection that I chose. To elaborate on the availablePeople List, if you select a person, that person can no longer be selected in future rows.

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <table id="tblPossessionChanges">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th><a href="#" class="buttonSmall" data-bind="click: addPossessionChange">Add</a></th>
        <th>From</th>
        <th>To</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: PossessionChanges">
      <tr>
        <td class="prompt">
          <a href="#" class="buttonSmall" data-bind="click: $root.removePossessionChange">Delete</a>           </td>
        <td>
          <select class="form-control" 
                  data-bind="options: $root.AvailableFrom, 
                             value: SelectedFrom,
                             optionsText: function(i) {return i.Name}, 
                             optionsValue: function(i) {return i.ID},
                             optionsCaption: 'Please select a Person...',
                             select2: { placeholder: 'Please select a Person...', allowClear: false}">             </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select class="form-control"
                  data-bind="options: $root.AvailableTo, 
                             value: SelectedTo, 
                             optionsText: function(i) {return i.Name}, 
                             optionsValue: function(i) {return i.ID},
                             optionsCaption: 'Please select a Person...',
                             select2: {placeholder: 'Please select a Person...', allowClear: false}">            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span id="changeTypeSpan" data-bind="text: ChangeType"></span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
 ko.bindingHandlers.select2 = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, bindingContext) {
      ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element,
        function() {
          $(element).select2('destroy');
        });
      var select2 = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(allBindingsAccessor().select2);
      $(element).select2(select2);
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, bindingContext) {
      var allBindings = allBindingsAccessor();
      if ("value" in allBindings) {
        if ((allBindings.select2.multiple || element.multiple) && allBindings.value().constructor != Array) {
          $(element).val(allBindings.value().split(',')).trigger('change');
        } else {
          $(element).val(allBindings.value()).trigger('change');
        }
      }
      $(element).trigger("change");
    }
    };

function BookPossessionTransferVM() {
    var self = this;

    self.AllFromList = ([{"IsAdult":false,"Name":"Bob","ID":38438}, {"IsAdult":false,"Name":"Gordon","ID":54686}, {"IsAdult":true,"Name":"Bill","ID":45645}, {"IsAdult":false,"Name":"Sue","ID":1231}, {"IsAdult":false,"Name":"Ling","ID":123578}, {"IsAdult":false,"Name":"Ivy","ID":78945}]);
    self.AllToList = ([{"IsAdult":false,"Name":"Adam","ID":38438}, {"IsAdult":false,"Name":"Geoff","ID":54686}, {"IsAdult":true,"Name":"Josh","ID":45645}, {"IsAdult":false,"Name":"Sam","ID":1231}, {"IsAdult":false,"Name":"Ming","ID":123578}, {"IsAdult":false,"Name":"Austin","ID":78945}, {"IsAdult":false,"Name":"Tsz","ID":78945}, {"IsAdult":true,"Name":"Ireylnn","ID":78945}, {"IsAdult":true,"Name":"Isabelle","ID":78945},{"IsAdult":true,"Name":"Vickey","ID":78945}]);

    self.PossessionChanges  = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.PossessionChanges.push(new PossessionChangeVM(self.PossessionChanges().length +1));

      self.GetPersonById = function (id) {
      return ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.AllFromList, function (person) {
          return person.ID === ko.unwrap(id);
        });
    }

 self.AvailableFrom = ko.computed(function() {
    var available = ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.AllFromList, function(item) {
      return !ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.PossessionChanges() , function (possessionChange) {
         var person = self.GetPersonById(possessionChange.SelectedFrom());
         if (person) {
          return person.ID === item.ID;
         } else {
           return false;
         }
      });
    });
    return available;
  });

    self.AvailableTo = ko.computed(function() {
    var available = ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.AllToList, function(item) {
      return !ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.PossessionChanges() , function (possessionChange) {
         var person = self.GetPersonById(possessionChange.SelectedTo());
         if (person) {
          return person.ID === item.ID;
         } else {
           return false;
         }
      });
    });
    return available;
  });

    self.addPossessionChange = function () {
      self.PossessionChanges.push(new PossessionChangeModel(self.PossessionChanges().length + 1));
    }

    self.removePossessionChangeChange = function(possessionChange) {
      self.PossessionChanges.remove(possessionChange);
    }
  }

  function PossessionChangeVM(possessionChangeId) {
    var self = this;

        self.possessionChangeId = ko.observable(possessionChangeId);
    self.SelectedFrom = ko.observable();
    self.SelectedTo = ko.observable();

    self.ChangeType = ko.pureComputed(function() {
      if (self.SelectedFrom() !== undefined && self.SelectedTo() !== undefined) {
        return 'Update';
      } else if (self.SelectedFrom() === undefined && self.SelectedTo() === undefined) {
          return '';
      } else if (self.SelectedFrom() === undefined) {
        return 'Add';
      } else if (self.SelectedTo() === undefined) {
        return 'Remove';
      } else { return ''; }
    });
  }

  function SelectedPerson(isAdult, name, id) {
    var self = this;

    self.IsAdult  = ko.observable(isAdult);
    self.Name = ko.observable(name);
    self.ID = ko.observable(id);
  }

  ko.applyBindings(new BookPossessionTransferVM());
```

Here's the jsfiddle as well: https://jsfiddle.net/cpd5w9he/11/
If you change person.ID to person, it works, but the options are then incorrect

Comment: When you select an item from the dropdown the value of "SelectedTo" correctly changes to that item's ID value. However, the dropdown options are then recomputed and that item is then removed from the list of options, causing the value of "SelectedTo" to revert back to undefined. You can't have a selected value that isn't part of the options list.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. So in order to get it to work correctly, I need to find a way to retain the ID value?

Comment: I'm not sure what "correctly" means in this case. Why are you trying to remove the item from the options list in the first place?

Comment: I'm trying to make it so if the item is selected, it can't be selected in future rows. Does that make sense? The objective is to have multiple rows with different people being add/removed/updated. For example if in the first row, I have bob selected in the From column. If I were to add another row, I wouldn't want the user to have to ability to select bob again

Comment: That makes sense. I'm not coming up with an elegant solution off hand, but I suspect each possessionChangeVM will have to calculate its options list separately and without removing its own selected value from the list

Comment: I'm looking to see if it's possible to disable a dropdownlist option have that occur for all of the dropdowns. Thank you for you help! If you find anything, let me know!

Comment: I don't know if `Select2` supports it but I like your idea of using the disabled attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Original problem:**
When you select an item from the dropdown the value of "SelectedTo" correctly changes to that item's ID value. However, the dropdown options are then recomputed and that item is then removed from the list of options, causing the value of "SelectedTo" to revert back to undefined. You can't have a selected value that isn't part of the options list.

**Solution:**
Here's a snippet that does what you want. I had to pass the root object down into the PossessionChangeVM which I'm not totally happy with, but it works. This way each possessionChangeVM builds its own list of available options using the FullList, and filtering only when the item has been used but is not the current item's selected one.

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.select2 = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, bindingContext) {
      ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element,
        function() {
          $(element).select2('destroy');
        });
      var select2 = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(allBindingsAccessor().select2);
      $(element).select2(select2);
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, bindingContext) {
      var allBindings = allBindingsAccessor();
      if ("value" in allBindings) {
        if ((allBindings.select2.multiple || element.multiple) && allBindings.value().constructor != Array) {
          $(element).val(allBindings.value().split(',')).trigger('change');
        } else {
          $(element).val(allBindings.value()).trigger('change');
        }
      }
      $(element).trigger("change");
    }
    };

function BookPossessionTransferVM() {
    var self = this;

    self.AllFromList = ([{"IsAdult":false,"Name":"Bob","ID":38438}, {"IsAdult":false,"Name":"Gordon","ID":54686}, {"IsAdult":true,"Name":"Bill","ID":45645}, {"IsAdult":false,"Name":"Sue","ID":1231}, {"IsAdult":false,"Name":"Ling","ID":123578}, {"IsAdult":false,"Name":"Ivy","ID":78945}]);
    self.AllToList = ([{"IsAdult":false,"Name":"Adam","ID":38438}, {"IsAdult":false,"Name":"Geoff","ID":54686}, {"IsAdult":true,"Name":"Josh","ID":45645}, {"IsAdult":false,"Name":"Sam","ID":1231}, {"IsAdult":false,"Name":"Ming","ID":123578}, {"IsAdult":false,"Name":"Austin","ID":78945}, {"IsAdult":false,"Name":"Tsz","ID":78945}, {"IsAdult":true,"Name":"Ireylnn","ID":78945}, {"IsAdult":true,"Name":"Isabelle","ID":78945},{"IsAdult":true,"Name":"Vickey","ID":78945}]);

  self.PossessionChanges  = ko.observableArray([]);
  
  self.UsedTo = ko.computed(function(){
     return self.PossessionChanges()
        .filter(function(item){
          return item.SelectedTo() != undefined;
        })
        .map(function(item){
          return item.SelectedTo();
        });
    });
    self.UsedFrom = ko.computed(function(){
     return self.PossessionChanges()
        .filter(function(item){
          return item.SelectedFrom() != undefined;
        })
        .map(function(item){
          return item.SelectedFrom();
        });
    });

    self.PossessionChanges.push(new PossessionChangeVM(self.PossessionChanges().length +1, self));
    
      self.GetPersonById = function (id) {
      return ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.AllFromList, function (person) {
          return person.ID === ko.unwrap(id);
        });
    }

    self.addPossessionChange = function () {
      self.PossessionChanges.push(new PossessionChangeVM(self.PossessionChanges().length + 1, self));
    }

    self.removePossessionChangeChange = function(possessionChange) {
      self.PossessionChanges.remove(possessionChange);
    }
  }

  function PossessionChangeVM(possessionChangeId, root) {
    var self = this;

  self.possessionChangeId = ko.observable(possessionChangeId);
    self.SelectedFrom = ko.observable();
    self.SelectedTo = ko.observable();
  
    
    self.AvailableFrom = ko.computed(function() {
      return ko.utils.arrayFilter(root.AllFromList, function(item) {
        return root.UsedFrom().indexOf(item.ID) < 0 || item.ID === self.SelectedFrom();
      });
   });
    
    self.AvailableTo = ko.computed(function() {
      return ko.utils.arrayFilter(root.AllToList, function(item) {
        return root.UsedTo().indexOf(item.ID) < 0 || item.ID === self.SelectedTo();
      });
   });

    self.ChangeType = ko.pureComputed(function() {
      if (self.SelectedFrom() !== undefined && self.SelectedTo() !== undefined) {
        return 'Update';
      } else if (self.SelectedFrom() === undefined && self.SelectedTo() === undefined) {
          return '';
      } else if (self.SelectedFrom() === undefined) {
        return 'Add';
      } else if (self.SelectedTo() === undefined) {
        return 'Remove';
      } else { return ''; }
    });
  }

  function SelectedPerson(isAdult, name, id) {
    var self = this;

    self.IsAdult  = ko.observable(isAdult);
    self.Name = ko.observable(name);
    self.ID = ko.observable(id);
  }
  
  ko.applyBindings(new BookPossessionTransferVM());
```

```css
#tblPossessionChanges {
    width: 70%;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    table-layout: fixed;
  }

  #tblPossessionChanges td, #tblPossessionChanges th {
    padding: 1rem;
  }

  #tblPossessionChanges thead th {
    text-align: center;
  }

  #tblPossessionChanges thead th:first-child {
    text-align: left;
    width: 10%;
  }

  #tblPossessionChanges tbody td:first-child {
    text-align: left;
    width: 10%;
  }

  #tblPossessionChanges > tbody > tr > td.prompt > a{
    font-weight: bold;
  }

  #tblPossessionChanges tbody td select{
    width: 75%
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.12/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div>
  <table id="tblPossessionChanges">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th><a href="#" class="buttonSmall" data-bind="click: addPossessionChange">Add</a></th>
        <th>From</th>
        <th>To</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: PossessionChanges">
      <tr>
        <td class="prompt">
          <a href="#" class="buttonSmall" data-bind="click: $root.removePossessionChange">Delete</a>           </td>
        <td>
          <select class="form-control" 
                  data-bind="options: AvailableFrom, 
                             value: SelectedFrom,
                             optionsText: function(i) {return i.Name}, 
                             optionsValue: function(i) {return i.ID},
                             optionsCaption: 'Please select a Person...',
                             select2: { placeholder: 'Please select a Person...', allowClear: false}">             </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select class="form-control"
                  data-bind="options: AvailableTo, 
                             value: SelectedTo, 
                             optionsText: function(i) {return i.Name}, 
                             optionsValue: function(i) {return i.ID},
                             optionsCaption: 'Please select a Person...',
                             select2: {placeholder: 'Please select a Person...', allowClear: false}">            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span id="changeTypeSpan" data-bind="text: ChangeType"></span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <br/>

</div>
```

Comment: Ooof. That's the route I was looking at too, but i really didn't like the idea of passing the root object down. Especially because if I'm sending this data as a JSON to my other model, that might cause issues. I''m going to have to run some tests and see if there are issues. If not, I'll mark your answer as correct. Thank you again!