# Knockout/Select2 remove selected options from dropdown options. Without passing down root model

Tags: knockout.js, jquery-select2

So I have a table with two dropdown lists (per row) that I'm using with knockout and select. I want to be able to disable or remove the selected options that already been selected.

Thanks to @Jason Spake I was able to understand the problem from [Knockout/Select2 Dropdownlist contains correct options, but now displays nothing as selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59994582/knockout-select2-dropdownlist-contains-correct-options-but-now-displays-nothing?noredirect=1#comment106103852_59994582). However the solution provided wasn't ideal because I do not want to be passing in the root model to the children models. Would anyone be able to help come up with a solution?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to throw together another snippet using your idea from the previous question to use the **disabled** attribute instead of removing the items altogether. Knockout has a handy select options binding called optionsAfterRender which lets you do some post processing on the generated options.

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.select2 = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, bindingContext) {
    ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element,
      function() {
        $(element).select2('destroy');
      });
    var select2 = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(allBindingsAccessor().select2);
    $(element).select2(select2);
  },
  update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, bindingContext) {
    var allBindings = allBindingsAccessor();
    if ("value" in allBindings) {
      if ((allBindings.select2.multiple || element.multiple) && allBindings.value().constructor != Array) {
        $(element).val(allBindings.value().split(',')).trigger('change');
      } else {
        $(element).val(allBindings.value()).trigger('change');
      }
    }
    $(element).trigger("change");
  }
};

function BookPossessionTransferVM() {
  var self = this;

  self.AllFromList = ([{ "IsAdult": false, "Name": "Bob", "ID": 38438 }, { "IsAdult": false, "Name": "Gordon", "ID": 54686 }, { "IsAdult": true, "Name": "Bill", "ID": 45645 }, { "IsAdult": false, "Name": "Sue", "ID": 1231 }, { "IsAdult": false, "Name": "Ling", "ID": 123578 }, { "IsAdult": false, "Name": "Ivy", "ID": 78945 }]);
  
  self.AllToList = ([{ "IsAdult": false, "Name": "Adam", "ID": 38438 }, { "IsAdult": false, "Name": "Geoff", "ID": 54686 }, { "IsAdult": true, "Name": "Josh", "ID": 45645 }, { "IsAdult": false, "Name": "Sam", "ID": 1231 }, { "IsAdult": false, "Name": "Ming", "ID": 123578 }, { "IsAdult": false, "Name": "Austin", "ID": 78945 }, { "IsAdult": false, "Name": "Tsz", "ID": 78945 }, { "IsAdult": true, "Name": "Ireylnn", "ID": 78945 }, { "IsAdult": true, "Name": "Isabelle", "ID": 78945 }, { "IsAdult": true, "Name": "Vickey", "ID": 78945 }]); 

  self.PossessionChanges = ko.observableArray([]);
  self.PossessionChanges.push(new PossessionChangeVM(self.PossessionChanges().length + 1));

  self.GetPersonById = function(id) {
    return ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.AllFromList, function(person) {
      return person.ID === ko.unwrap(id);
    });
  }

  self.UsedTo = ko.computed(function() {
    return self.PossessionChanges()
      .filter(function(item) {
        return item.SelectedTo() != undefined;
      })
      .map(function(item) {
        return item.SelectedTo();
      });
  });
  self.UsedFrom = ko.computed(function() {
    return self.PossessionChanges()
      .filter(function(item) {
        return item.SelectedFrom() != undefined;
      })
      .map(function(item) {
        return item.SelectedFrom();
      });
  });

  self.setOptionDisable = function(option, item) {
    if (item)
      ko.applyBindingsToNode(option, {
        disable: item.disabled
      }, item);
  }

  self.AvailableFrom = ko.computed(function() {
    var available = self.AllFromList.slice();
    for (var i = 0; i < available.length; i++) {
      available[i].disabled = available[i].disabled || ko.observable(false);
      available[i].disabled((self.UsedFrom().indexOf(available[i].ID) >= 0));
    }
    return available;
  });

  self.AvailableTo = ko.computed(function() {
    var available = self.AllToList.slice();
    for (var i = 0; i < available.length; i++) {
      available[i].disabled = available[i].disabled || ko.observable(false);
      available[i].disabled((self.UsedTo().indexOf(available[i].ID) >= 0));
    }
    return available;
  });

  self.addPossessionChange = function() {
    self.PossessionChanges.push(new PossessionChangeVM(self.PossessionChanges().length + 1));
  }

  self.removePossessionChangeChange = function(possessionChange) {
    self.PossessionChanges.remove(possessionChange);
  }
}

function PossessionChangeVM(possessionChangeId) {
  var self = this;

  self.possessionChangeId = ko.observable(possessionChangeId);
  self.SelectedFrom = ko.observable();
  self.SelectedTo = ko.observable();

  self.ChangeType = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    if (self.SelectedFrom() !== undefined && self.SelectedTo() !== undefined) {
      return 'Update';
    } else if (self.SelectedFrom() === undefined && self.SelectedTo() === undefined) {
      return '';
    } else if (self.SelectedFrom() === undefined) {
      return 'Add';
    } else if (self.SelectedTo() === undefined) {
      return 'Remove';
    } else {
      return '';
    }
  });
}

function SelectedPerson(isAdult, name, id) {
  var self = this;

  self.IsAdult = ko.observable(isAdult);
  self.Name = ko.observable(name);
  self.ID = ko.observable(id);
}

ko.applyBindings(new BookPossessionTransferVM());
```

```css
#tblPossessionChanges {
  width: 70%;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

#tblPossessionChanges td,
#tblPossessionChanges th {
  padding: 1rem;
}

#tblPossessionChanges thead th {
  text-align: center;
}

#tblPossessionChanges thead th:first-child {
  text-align: left;
  width: 10%;
}

#tblPossessionChanges tbody td:first-child {
  text-align: left;
  width: 10%;
}

#tblPossessionChanges>tbody>tr>td.prompt>a {
  font-weight: bold;
}

#tblPossessionChanges tbody td select {
  width: 75%
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.12/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div>
  <table id="tblPossessionChanges">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th><a href="#" class="buttonSmall" data-bind="click: addPossessionChange">Add</a></th>
        <th>From</th>
        <th>To</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: PossessionChanges">
      <tr>
        <td class="prompt">
          <a href="#" class="buttonSmall" data-bind="click: $root.removePossessionChange">Delete</a> </td>
        <td>
          <select class="form-control" 
                  data-bind="options: $root.AvailableFrom, 
                             value: SelectedFrom,
                             optionsText: function(i) {return i.Name}, 
                             optionsValue: function(i) {return i.ID},
                             optionsCaption: 'Please select a Person...',
                             optionsAfterRender: $root.setOptionDisable,
                             select2: { placeholder: 'Please select a Person...', allowClear: false}">          
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select class="form-control"
                  data-bind="options: $root.AvailableTo, 
                             value: SelectedTo, 
                             optionsText: function(i) {return i.Name}, 
                             optionsValue: function(i) {return i.ID},
                             optionsCaption: 'Please select a Person...',
                             optionsAfterRender: $root.setOptionDisable,
                             select2: { placeholder: 'Please select a Person...', allowClear: false}">            
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span id="changeTypeSpan" data-bind="text: ChangeType"></span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <br/>

</div>
```

Comment: Why are you so brilliant? Thank you so much! I was looking into the disabled but wasn't able to come up with anything

Comment: It must be all those experimental injections I signed up for in college. Glad I could help!

Comment: Hi @Jason Spake, I'm trying to get it to work on my end but for some reason `(self.UsedFrom().indexOf(available[i].ID)` is not working like it should be. It's only returning a -1

Comment: @M.Bi Does your code differ from the snippet above? Do you have a fiddle I could peek at?

Comment: I had to change the 2nd line of the available computed function to `var keysInUse = ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.UsedFrom(),
          function(item) {
            return available[i].ID() == item();
          });
        available[i].disabled(keysInUse ? (keysInUse().length >= 0) : false);`

Comment: @M.Bi Do you get any errors in your console? Also why are there parens at the end of `item` in your comparison? Has the UsedFrom function changed to emit an array of observables instead of an array of numbers?

Comment: @M.Bi Oh so no more problems with the "only returning -1"? Great!

Comment: yup! Thank you so much for all of your help!